# How to link facebook app and page together

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I've created a FB page for a client. In the process I also created a FB application, to get an App id that I could add to the FB meta tags of the website of my client.

Now I'd like to create a "fan get" iframe for this FB page.
I've found [this](http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-use-a-fan-gate-on-your-iframe-tab-to-hide-content-until-someone-likes-your-facebook-fan-page/) great tutorial that explains it all.

My problems are:

1. How can I link the app with the page?
2. I'm trying to create a new tab in my page, where the app will be loaded, and eventually this tab will be displayed by default when a user didn't click the "like" yet.
   But I cannot find anywhere in the page settings something to add a new tab.
   I've seen old tutorials where it was part of the settings but I can't find it anymore.

Between the deprecated methods and the new upcoming ones, I'm lost.